# Swift Dictionary lookup causing compile-time error

Tags: arrays, dictionary, collections, swift

I'm dipping my toe into Swift, but have run into an issue that has me slightly confused. Given an integer index I'm trying to fetch the corresponding key of a Dictionary and return the value associated with it.

Using the following structure as an example:

```
Class CustomClass {
    private var collection: [String: [SifterIssue]] = ["MyStringKey": [MyCustomCollectionClass]()]

    /* ... */
}
```

I tried to solve the problem like so:

```
var keys = Array(self.collection.keys)
var key: String = keys[section] as String
return self.collection[key].count // error is flagged here
```

But found that this results in a compiler error, which states that **'String' is not convertible to 'DictionaryIndex'**. Stumped, I tried a slightly more verbose solution and was surprised to find that this compiled and worked without issue.

```
var keys = Array(self.collection.keys)
var key: String = keys[section] as String
var collection: [MyCustomCollectionClass] = self.collection[key]! as [MyCustomCollectionClass]
return issues.count
```

Can anyone explain to me why the first solution refuses to compile?

Comment: `self.collection[key]` is an optional `[SifterIssue]?`, try using a `?` or `!` after `[key]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fatal potential error is a really bad idea. The whole reason for Optionals is to prevent crashes at runtime.

```
func collectionCount(#section: Int) -> Int? {
    var keys = Array(self.collection.keys)
    if section < keys.count {
    var key = keys[section] as String
        println("key: \(key)")
        return self.collection[key]!.count
    }
    else {
        // handle error here
        return nil
    }
}
```

Throwing in "!" unwrapping without knowing that the value can **never** be nil is much worse than the Objective-C handling of nil. If this becomes the standard way of handling Optionals by a substantial number of developers Swift will be a disaster. Please do not do this.

Comment: You're correct that blindly unwrapping without testing for nil would be a mistake. I did so for brevity, but have removed my answer as yours is structured nicely and will hopefully help others in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Won't calling `keys[section]` with a `section` that's out of range of the `keys` array also be a fatal error?

Comment: Yes, fixed. Is there a better way than an explicit test for the index?

Comment: @Zaph I can't think of anything offhand. There is a built-in lazy property for the array of keys though: `self.collection.keys.array`. So, after bounds checking `section`, you could do: `let key = collection.keys.array[section]` `return collection[key]!.count`. I don't think `keys[section] != nil` is needed since `keys[section]` will always return a valid key as long as `section` is inside the array bounds.

Comment: @MikeS I didn't know about the lazy property for keys. Helpful!

Comment: That seems correct. It seems wrong to explicitly unwrap without checking.

Comment: @Zaph I think I came up with a more "swifty" way of doing the index check. I put it in a separate answer as it seemed too much to put in a comment here.

Answer (score 2):

As @Zaph said, ignoring potential fatal errors is a bad idea and it's something that swift was, in part, designed to help with. This is the most "swifty" code I could come up:

```
func collectionCount(#section: Int) -> Int? {
    switch section {
    case 0..<collection.count: // Make sure section is within the bounds of collection's keys array
        let key = collection.keys.array[section] // Grab the key from the collection's keys array
        return collection[key]!.count // We can force unwrap collection[key] here because we know that key exists in collection
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

It uses the range/pattern matching feature of swift's `switch` statement to make sure that `section` in the bounds of `collection`'s `keys` array; that felt more "swifty" than using `if`, mainly because I couldn't find a way to use swift's `Range` in an `if` statement. It also uses `collection.keys` lazy property `array` as a shortcut instead of creating a new `Array` with `Array(collection.keys)`. Since we've already made sure that `section` is within the bounds of `collection.keys`, we can forcibly unwrap `collection[key]!` when we get its `count`.

Just for fun, I also made a generic function that takes a collection as input to generalize things:

```
func collectionCount<T,U>(#collection: [T:[U]], #section: Int) -> Int? {
    switch section {
    case 0..<collection.count: // Make sure section is within the bounds of collection's keys array
        let key = collection.keys.array[section] // Grab the key from the collection's keys array
        return collection[key]!.count // We can force unwrap collection[key] here because we know that key exists in collection
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

`[T:[U]]` basically says that `collection` needs to be a `Dictionary` with key `T` whose values are an `Array` of `U`.

Comment: I have to give @Mike S props for a unique and concise solution. More "swift?", probably based on the amount of head-scratching the next developer will do upon encountering this. :-) Considering the negative impact that Optionals have on developers I feel the Swift developers owe us better language constructs to deal with them. For me a good language is one that gets out of the way, one where I spend more time think about my code and less about the language constraints. Swift, IMO, does not meet this.